# Frequency response of the waveguide

Tags: signal, frequency, bandwidth, waveguide

So, I have signal in the waveguide that is transmitted by two modes of radiation, for which the delay is for example \$\tau_1=6\,\text{ns},\, \tau_2=6.5\,\text{ns}\$, respectively. And the energy supplied to the receiver by each mode is the same.

My question is about calculating \$3\,\text{dB}\$ width of the bandwidth of the channel (containing the constant component - but I'm not sure what that means). I know I need to substract this two modes one from the other (with an absolute value):

\$ d=|6\,\text{ns}−6.5\,\text{ns}| \$

\$ d=0.5\,\text{ns}\$

And next I multiply my \$d\cdot2\$ and divide one by my result. So:

\$\frac1{2d}\$

Ant this gives me \$1\,\text{GHz}\$, and this is the perfectly correct answer!

But I don't know

- why this formula works?
- why we don't use the lambda formula for our waveguide frequency?
- what does it mean that the channel was created in the basic band?

Comment: what **is** \$\lambda\$ within your waveguide?

Comment: You don't mention "basic band" anywhere in your question, and as far as I can tell, it's not a common term. Can you cite exactly where that comes from? We know *base band* in the context of channels (but that has not much to do with waveguides) or we know *fundamental modes* in waveguides. Maybe you meant one of these?

Comment: @Marcus Müller using Lambda, we can calculate wavelength of the wave - so the frequency. [Here is the formula](http://d2xunoxnk3vwmv.cloudfront.net/uploads/lambda-guide.jpg)

Comment: so, how does that formula relate to your \$\tau\$? (it's really all a matter of replacing \$f\$ and other variables with your given values; I'm asking this so you can do it on your own!)

Comment: @Marcus Müller yeah, but I don;t know what to do with my c which is 3*10^8, because I think I can't put this in my formula

Comment: @MarcusMüller and about this basic band. The question on the exercises was arranged in this way "Calculate the 3 dB bandwidth for the channel that was created in the base band."

Comment: @MarcusMüller I transformed this formula on paper and typed this on wolfram, can you chceck it? 
[Formula](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?fbclid=IwAR26dlOJvwWLZPFyXoSnNKMXGUVwNadPsUAMmzO1IFlMYJPJzK4FrmPJX_c&i=(c+sqrt(4+a%5E2+%2B+l%5E2))%2F(2+a+l))
btw. l is for lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the formula, because I did some research, so it is said that:

> "It can be shown that almost regardless of the details of the course
>   of the channel characteristic - as long as its frequency response is
>   equal to W - the effect of channel crossing is to widen the pulse
>   width by time Δτ≈1 / W."

So that almost answers my question, the only problem I have is why Δτ is multiplied by two? Otherwise, it wouldn't match to my result. Can anyone know?